# How to add OnTouch Event in android with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I have a problem. I am using SkiaSharp to make a TriangleGrid. Now I am doing drawing the Grid, but now I want to touch a triangle in the grid to color it. To do that I need to add a TouchEvent to the SKCanvasView, but I dont know how to do that.
 On the internet I can find the next example:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/finger-paint
- https://github.com/mattleibow/SkiaSharpDemo/blob/master/SkiaSharpDemo/SkiaSharpDemo/MainPage.xaml

But I am using Xamarin Android and those example doesn't work in my code. I also tried to use:

```
skiaView = FindViewById<SkiaSharp.Views.Android.SKCanvasView>(Resource.Id.skiaView);
skiaView.SetOnTouchListener += OnTouch;
```

But that gives me the error: "Cannot assign to 'SetOnTouchListener' because it's a 'method group'"

Can anyone help me to get a TouchListener on my SkiaSharp canvas!?

Comment: the github code you are looking at is NOT the sample that goes with the finger painting doc

Comment: Can you tell me what I need to add in the .axml file?

Comment: What axml file?  Your questions are all tagged with Xamarin.Forms so I presume that is what you are actually using, not Xamarin Android.  You would do yourself a huge favor to sit down and actually take the time to review the code for the finger paint sample.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake... I am using xamarin.android. I need an example for xamarin.android

Comment: see TouchEffect.cs in the Android project of the FingerPaint sample.

Comment: The last error I get when I litteraly copy TouchEffect.cs is on line 197 with the following error: `'TouchEffect' does not contain a definition for 'OnTouchAction' and no accessible extension method 'OnTouchAction' accepting a first argument of type 'TouchEffect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to add event ,you could set `OnTouch` event like this:

```
skiaView= FindViewById<SKCanvasView>(Resource.Id.skiaView);
skiaView.Touch += onTouch;

private void onTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
  {
     Toast.MakeText(this, "touch", ToastLength.Short).Show();
  }
```

or :

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity,View.IOnTouchListener
  {
    private SKCanvasView skiaView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        skiaView= FindViewById<SKCanvasView>(Resource.Id.skiaView);
        skiaView.SetOnTouchListener(this);  
        ...
      }
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
      {
        Toast.MakeText(this,"touch",ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924506/how-to-call-a-method-with-eventhandler